# What's the pythonic method of doing multiple ors?

Tags: python

Is there a way to do effectively do:

```
if operator != ('+' or '-' or '*' or '/'):
```

without having to do

```
operator != '+' and operator != '-' and operator != '*'
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use the `in` operator

```
if operator not in ('+', '-', '/')
```

Comment: ..and [`operator not in {'+', '-', '/'}` in Python 3.2+](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.2.html#optimizations)

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary -- Ooo ... I didn't realize that the python3.2 optimizer was that smart.  That's fantastic.

Comment: Works with python 2 as well https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#set-displays

Comment: @srj It is not about how sets are displayed, it is about the optimization done by [peephole.c](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Python/peephole.c#L84) in Python 3.2+ when it sees set literals being used with `in` and `not in` operators. See [issue 6690](http://bugs.python.org/issue6690) for details.

Answer (score 0):

Effective to read solution would be: `if operator in ('+', '-', '*', '/')` or simply `if operator in '+-*/'` (thanks @kindall) which is like looking for a char in a string. I personally find it less readable though.

Otherwize you use a dictionnary (for instance, to bind a function to each operator) and just use exceptions:

```
ops = {'+': 'plus', '-': 'minus', '*': 'times', '/': 'div'}
operator = '/'
try:
  print ops[operator]
except KeyError:
  print "Unknow operation (%s)" % (operator)
```

Comment: `operator in "+-*/"` ... no need to use a list since the operators are all single chars.