# Pythonic Way to have multiple Or's when conditioning in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

Basically instead of writing

```
data[data['pos'] == "QB" | data['pos'] == "DST" | ...]
```

where there are many cases I want to check

I was trying to do something similar to this [What's the pythonic method of doing multiple ors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26245252/whats-the-pythonic-method-of-doing-multiple-ors).  However, this

```
data[data['pos'] in ("QB", "DST", ...)]
```

doesn't work.

I read the documentation here http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/gotchas.html but I'm still having issues.

Comment: What do you want to achieve? Just to check whether `data['pos']` is equal to some data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for is [`Series.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.isin.html) . Example -

```
data[data['pos'].isin(("QB", "DST", ...))]
```

This would check if each value from `pos` is in the list of values - `("QB", "DST", ...)` . Similar to what your multiple `|` would do.