# How to specify multiple elements using pandas.Series.isin

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a working code that I am trying to reduce

```
df['Criteria'] = (df['Alpha'] == 3) | (df['Alpha'] == 4)
```

I tried with error the below (TypeError: isin() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given)

```
df['Criteria'] = df['Alpha'].isin(3,4)
```

I took reference from [Pythonic Way to have multiple Or's when conditioning in a dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32976477/pythonic-way-to-have-multiple-ors-when-conditioning-in-a-dataframe)

Can anyone advise me on this please? 
Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are close, need `list`,`tuple`, `array` or `set` in [`isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.isin.html):

> **Series.isin(values)**
>
> **values** : set or list-like
>
> The sequence of values to test. Passing in a single string will raise a TypeError. Instead, turn a single string into a list of one element.

```
df['Criteria2'] = df['Alpha'].isin([3,4])
```

Comment: @JNg please, accept the answer as the correct answer if it solved your problem.